# We need to release c++ prebuilt library on Android, how to organize resources used by our lib?

Tags: android, android-ndk

We have a c++ project on android, which will be built into .a then release the .a to our users.

The problem is, we have many resource files, and these resources' path is necessary because some 3rd-party libs need them.

The limitation on android is: if we want to put a file in Android APK, we must package it in res or assets and it is not single file any more, so how can we organize our resources?

Our plan is to require our users to package our resources in APK's Assets, then we can extract them to other folder, but it's not user-friendly, do you have any better idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ android project, it sounds me weird, may be, you would like to say that you have c++ arm crosscompiled static library .a which it is able to load in an Android project.

I guess  you want to share a library which uses many resources, and you need the elegant way to distribute.

Try to create a .jar file which it has native functions:

- Firstly create your core class exporting functions and define your
  public native functions to JNI.
- Don't use activities, if you need to access to activity context, pass
  through parameters.
- If you want to use resources, your layouts will not be able to use in
  your parent android project.
- You can use drawable files and you can add layout files    programatically (with activity context).
- If you are going to use some resources such as xml config files, put 
  in the res/raw folder or in assets folder.

If you have good Java and JNI skills, this task is not so difficult.

Hope the advices help you.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. our project is not using java, and doesn't have any GUI. you can consider it as an image processing lib.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand exactly what do you want to do. If you want to provide a image processing library, create a .so library which links this .a processing module, because, android doesn't support static libraries. To avoid internal linking problems use --whole-archive option and I suggest to use cmake to make easier the linking.

Comment: sorry I didn't describe my question clearly.     .a or .so doesn't matter since our user will link it into their own library.  Let's assume it's .so, do you have any good idea to organize its resources. If I am not wrong, we have to put resources in assets/res on android, which requires our user organize their APK as we expect. do you have other idea?               BTW, your "--whole-archive" helps me a lot. I was just debugging an issue caused by it. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to develope a **NativeActivity**. If you follow the [proper documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html), you could create a working app to do whatever you want. If you want to open assets, process, you can do it, and launch this app from another one.

If you really want a single library to be used, Just do it in c/cpp, and initialize it with a JNI function call providing the asset path and aassetmanager, and use the [AAssetManager object](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html?hl=es) in native. You will need to include jni.h, of course you will need to crosscompile the library using the NDK toolchain, and gradle or cmake toolchain scripts.